# Azure Mobile Service: Cannot connect to local instance hosted in IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express, azure-mobile-services

I've got a weird problem with Azure Mobile Services hosted on IIS Express. I searched around SO and the web, but I did not find anything that works for my problem, so here it is:

When I create a new Azure Mobile Service project in Visual Studio (VS 2013 Upd. 4, Azure Tools 2.2, Admin mode), then all seems to be fine at first sight, and I can interact with it as expected through the test webpage that pops up after (Ctrl+) F5.

However, when I try to call the service programmatically from a client, e.g. like in this test

```
[TestFixture]
public class Fixture
{
    private static readonly MobileServiceClient ServiceClient =
        new MobileServiceClient("http://localhost:64481/");

    [Test]
    public async void Test()
    {
        IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> table = ServiceClient.GetTable<TodoItem>();
        List<TodoItem> items = await table.ToListAsync();

        Assert.That(items.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
    }
}
```

... then I (most of the time) cannot access the service, and I get this exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [::1]:64481
```

The weird thing is that the above test occasionally succeeds, but most of the time fails with this exception. I cannot find any regularity behind this. It seems like there's a bigger chance for it to succeed if IISExpress was freshly started and the test webpage is open, but that's not a strict rule.

So far, I have monitored the `iisexpress.exe` process with ProcessMonitor and executed the command line manually from the console (Admin mode). When I do that, again the test page is working as expected and I can see the requests coming through at the console. I can also see that in the error scenario no request is reaching the web server. So obviously it gets blocked by something in the chain that comes beforehand.

Remark: The error also occurs without any firewall running.

I'm totally stuck on this, having no idea what the problem could be, not even what else I could do to find out what's going on. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen this error before. Have you tried using a different port? Are you able to deploy the service to Azure without issues?

Comment: @lindydonna I found out that the problem is not specific to Azure (or any other technology) but always happens when I try to issue a request against localhost per C# code, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394068/web-request-fails-but-only-for-localhost-and-when-using-system-net-httpwebreque).